# How to fill a full background color in Ncurses using derwin() subwindow function?

Tags: ncurses, curses

Is there a way to fill a full background color using `derwin()` subwindow function in Ncurses?

This is my program below. I am expecting all white background in the sonny subwindow but unfortunately not what I expected to appear.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    WINDOW *pops,*sonny;
    int x2, y2, x4, y4;

    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);

    x2 = COLS >> 1;
    y2 = LINES >> 1;
    x4 = (COLS - x2) / 2;
    y4 = (LINES - y2) / 2;

    /* create parent and subwindow with derwin() */
    pops = newwin(y2, x2, y4, x4);
    sonny = derwin(pops, y4, x4, 7, 5);
    if (sonny == NULL) {
        endwin();
        puts("Unable to create subwindow\n");
        return(1);
    }

    /* color windows and splash some text */
    wbkgd(pops,COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvwaddstr(pops, 2, 2, "Hello, son.");
    wrefresh(pops);
    wbkgd(sonny,COLOR_PAIR(2));
    wborder(sonny, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mvwaddstr(sonny, 3, 3, "Hello, Dad.");
    wrefresh(sonny);
    wgetch(sonny);

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: derwin.c program]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from [`derwin`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-dupwin) (like [`subwin`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-subwin)) shares memory with the parent window:

> The subwindow shares memory with the window *orig*, its ancestor, so that changes made to one  window will  affect both windows.

Keeping this in mind when reading the manpage for [`wbkgd`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html#h3-bkgd):

> If  the  cell  uses color, and that does not match the color in the
> current  background,  the  library  updates  ***only***   the   non-color
> attributes,  first  removing  those  which  may  have come from the
> current  background,  and  then  adding  attributes  from  the  new
> background.

The background character for the derived window does not match the colors of the cells because that was set by the first `wbkgd` call, on the parent window:

```c
    wbkgd(pops,COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

You can make the background *character* of the derived window the same as that (without modifying the cells) using `wbkgdset`,

```c
    wbkgdset(sonny,COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

After doing that, the color of the background character matches the contents of the derived window, and this paragraph applies:

> If  the  cell uses color, and that matches the color in the current
> background, the library removes attributes which may have come from
> the current background and adds attributes from the new background.
> It finishes by setting the cell to  use  the  color  from  the  new
> background.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the detailed explanation @Thomas Dickey. So, my expectation is not correct as derive window background color is inherited or matched the parent window background color.

Comment: The background character is not inherited (and if it were, it wouldn't change the problem arising from shared content of the windows).